# Transforming XML to CSV using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a special case of transforming a XML document to a CSV document.
In my XML I have the following structure:

```
<Pictures>
    <Picture>
        <File>picture1.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>pictureX.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>picture999.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>picture1.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <ID>555</ID>
        <File>detailX.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>detail</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>detail1.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>detail</Purpose>
    </Picture>
</Pictures>
```

What I want is the followind CSV:

```
normal1;normal2;normal3;detail1;detail2
picture1.jpg;pictureX.jpg;picture999.jpg;
```

Up to this point I am able to convert it correctly. But the problem is, that there are many other Pictures elements in my XML that can contain Picture elements with other purpose values.

Example:

```
<Pictures>
    <Picture>
        <File>picture1.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
</Pictures>
<Pictures>
    <Picture>
        <File>picture2.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>detail</Purpose>
    </Picture>
</Pictures>
<Pictures>
    <Picture>
        <File>pictureX.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>pictureY.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>detail</Purpose>
    </Picture>
</Pictures>
<Pictures>
    <Picture>
        <File>pictureA.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>pictureB.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>normal</Purpose>
    </Picture>
    <Picture>
        <File>pictureD.jpg</File>
        <Purpose>detail</Purpose>
    </Picture>
</Pictures>
```

As CSV:

```
normal1;normal2;detail1
picture1.jpg;;
;;picture2.jpg;
pictureX.jpg;;pictureY.jpg
pictureA.jpg;pictureB.jpg;pictureD.jpg
```

I have no Idea if it possible to do that only by using XSLT or how to do. The transformation has to be fast (one XML can easily contain 38k Pictures elements) .

If anyone have an idea please post.
Thank you in advance!

André

Comment: So do you want one line in the CSV for each `<Pictures>` element?

Comment: Yes, for each <Pictures> element I want one row in the resulting csv.

Comment: Well, this presents a bit of a logistic problem. The first `pictures` has a single `detail`, and the second has a single `normal`. How should the columns be arranged in this case? Does the order matter, or can they be horizontally rearranged (e.g. to list the column names in alphabetical order)?

Comment: The order is not important. The only thing that is important is, that the column headers are matching the column values. All Picture elements that have a Purpose "detail" should be in a column like "detailX". I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: I understand what you are asking, however the second example is not valid XML. Are you sure that XML is to be processed by an XSLT. XML can only have ONE root node this has many. Plus there are multipule opening tags and nothing closing them line 6 and 7. Can you confirm this Example to is correct.

Comment: Oh I removed some misspellings in the second xml. Now it is Valid (of course in real there is some root node around)

Comment: The correct way is to use a comma as seperator. But some target systems need the seperator to be a semicolon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic XML to CSV conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951498/generic-xml-to-csv-conversion)