# Generic XML to CSV conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert a dynamic XML to CSV. I searched for various options to achieve this but did not find a suitable answer.

The structure of the XML is dynamic - It can be a product data, a geography data or any such thing. So, I am not able to use predefined XSL or castor conversion.

The tag names should form the header of the CSV.
For example :

```
<Ctry>
  <datarow>
     <CtryName>Ctry1</CtryName>
     <CtryID>12361</CtryID>
    <State>
      <datarow>
         <StateName>State1</StateName>
         <StateID>12361</StateID>
        <City>
           <datarow>
              <CityName>City1</CityName>
               <CityID>12361</CityID>
           </datarow>
        </City>
      </datarow>
      <datarow>
         <StateName>State2</StateName>
         <StateID>12361</StateID>
      </datarow>
      </State>
  </datarow>
</Ctry>
```

The CSV should look like :

```
Header: CtryName   CtryId     StateName  StateId     CityName   CityID
Row1:   Ctry1       12361     State1     12361       City1      12361
Row2:   Ctry1       12361     State2     12361
```

Could you please recommend the apt thing to use to address this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a program to read your mind about the structure of your XML.

Comment: -1 Have you written any code that might help you? If you just want someone to write code for you, you might have better luck on a Freelancer site.

Comment: Yes. I have written a SAX based parser but that is not able to fully solve this problem. Hence I was on the look out for any java library which readily does this. I have the XSD of the XML. Based on that, I am trying to write a generic XSLT which would transform it to CSV. Any pointers in writing the generic XSLT would help.

Comment: I have just written a generic XSLT solution to this problem.  I don't see why it has to be flagged as off-topic for XSLT.

Comment: I have also made available for free some developer resources on my web site for going from CSV to XML.  The original requirement posted here seems very generic: the only assumption I made is that `<datarow>` elements define the suite of fields to capture in CSV. I make no other assumptions about element names, so it is a very generic solution.  Why does everyone think this isn't just another XSLT stylesheet writing task?

Comment: I've reposted the question and included a working solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991683/generic-xml-to-csv-conversion-retry

Comment: @G.KenHolman please do not do that in the future. I have merged them.

Comment: How is it possible to add an answer to a question that has been put "on hold".  I would have gladly posted the answer to this question here where it is asked, without creating a duplicate, but there was no opportunity in the user interface that I saw with which to do so.  Thank you for merging them, but I would appreciate being given direction rather than being slapped on the wrist.

Comment: Furthermore, this question appears to still be marked "on hold" ... by which mechanism is this hold released?

Comment: So the original poster requested a solution using XSLT 1.0 and the StackOverflow user interface did not present me with the option to add an alternative answer.  Would someone please indicate how answers are added to a question that has been put "on hold"?  And can someone please take this question off "on hold" since it is not a superfluous question?

Comment: @G.KenHolman [The help center has information on re-opening a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). Basically you just need to edit it into shape and then hope that people vote to re-open it.

Comment: Thank you for that guidance, Matthew.  Being told previously "do not do that" was very unhelpful, as the documentation at http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions reads "When a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked [on hold], and will no longer accept answers."  I'm not going to let a perfectly good answer simply be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a transcript illustrating the execution of a generic stylesheet to do such conversion.  The only assumption made by the stylesheet is the element `<datarows>`.  The structure given implies the use of child elements based on the requested results:

Data:

```
  T:\ftemp>type xml2csv.xml 
  <Ctry>
    <datarow>
       <CtryName>Ctry1</CtryName>
       <CtryID>12361</CtryID>
      <State>
        <datarow>
           <StateName>State1</StateName>
           <StateID>12361</StateID>
          <City>
             <datarow>
                <CityName>City1</CityName>
                 <CityID>12361</CityID>
             </datarow>
          </City>
        </datarow>
        <datarow>
           <StateName>State2</StateName>
           <StateID>12361</StateID>
        </datarow>
        </State>
    </datarow>
  </Ctry>
```

Execution:

```
  T:\ftemp>call xslt2 xml2csv.xml xml2csv.xsl 
  CtryName,CtryID,StateName,StateID,CityName,CityID
  Ctry1,12361,State1,12361,City1,12361
  Ctry1,12361,State2,12361
```

Stylesheet:

```
  T:\ftemp>type xml2csv.xsl 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="fields" 
                select="distinct-values(//datarow/*[not(*)]/name(.))"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--header row-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$fields" separator=","/>

    <!--body-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>

    <!--final line terminator-->
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--elements only process elements, not text-->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--these elements are CSV fields-->
  <xsl:template match="datarow/*[not(*)]">
    <!--replicate ancestors if necessary-->
    <xsl:if test="position()=1 and ../preceding-sibling::datarow">
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::datarow[position()>1]/*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:call-template name="doThisField"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="doThisField"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--put out a field ending the previous field and escaping content-->
  <xsl:template name="doThisField">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name(.)=$fields[1]">
        <!--previous line terminator-->
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--previous field terminator-->
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!--field value escaped per RFC4180-->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(.,'&#x22;') or 
                      contains(.,',') or
                      contains(.,'&#xa;')">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'&#x22;','&#x22;&#x22;')"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the above code escapes the individual fields per RFC4180.

My profile has a link to my web site where you will find a directory of free XML resources including an XSLT stylesheet to convert RFC4180 CSV files into XML files.

This is an XSLT 1.0 solution to the answer, as requested by the original poster:

```
t:\ftemp>type xml2csv1.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="firstFieldName" 
              select="name((//datarow/*[not(*)])[1])"/>

<xsl:key name="names" match="datarow/*[not(*)]" use="name(.)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!--header row-->
  <xsl:for-each select="//datarow/*[not(*)]
                        [generate-id(.)=
                         generate-id(key('names',name(.))[1])]">
    <xsl:if test="position()>1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <!--body-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>

  <!--final line terminator-->
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!--elements only process elements, not text-->
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--these elements are CSV fields-->
<xsl:template match="datarow/*[not(*)]">
  <!--replicate ancestors if necessary-->
  <xsl:if test="position()=1 and ../preceding-sibling::datarow">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::datarow[position()>1]/*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:call-template name="doThisField"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:call-template name="doThisField"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--put out a field ending the previous field and escaping content-->
<xsl:template name="doThisField">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name(.)=$firstFieldName">
      <!--previous line terminator-->
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!--previous field terminator-->
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <!--field value escaped per RFC4180-->
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(.,'&#x22;') or 
                    contains(.,',') or
                    contains(.,'&#xa;')">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote"/>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!--escape a double quote in the current node value with two double quotes-->
<xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
  <xsl:param name="rest" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($rest,'&#x22;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($rest,'&#x22;')"/>
      <xsl:text>""</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
        <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($rest,'&#x22;')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$rest"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for the reply... I tried to run my java program but I am getting this exception.. "Exception occurred: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: distinct-values" ... I tried with different versions of xalan.jar. Could you let me know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What you call a "problem" is just that you did not indicate in your original question you are limited to XSLT 1.0.  I gave you an answer using XSLT 2.0.  Since I can see no way in the user interface to post an alternative answer, I've edited this answer to include an XSLT 1.0 version of the solution.

Comment: Hi Ken, This xslt works great! Thanks so much!